# how Detecting Collisions in phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

"what i am trying to do is when the 2 images hit each other they both stop i am making this for a game  the 2 images are just going into each other  plse help me the code is below the git fof this project is [https://github.com/CrystalX775/intro-phaser.js"](https://github.com/CrystalX775/intro-phaser.js%22)

```
function preload(){
    this.load.image('intro2', '/images/Screenshot 2023-10-20 10.23.58 AM.png');
    this.load.image('intro1', '/images/Screenshot 2023-10-20 10.20.39 AM.png');
this.load.audio('madcityintro','/sounds/mad city intro.mp3' );
}
function create(){
gameState.m = this.add.sprite(-179,  200, 'intro1')
gameState.mad = this.sound.add('madcityintro')
gameState.mad.play(); 
gameState.w = this.add.sprite(989,  200, 'intro2') 
}  

function update(){
 gameState.m.x += 7;
gameState.w.x +=-7;
}


const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    backgroundColor: "b9eaff",
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade: {
        gravity: { y: 200 },
        enableBody: true,
      }
    },
    scene: {
      preload,
      create,
      update
    }
  };
  
  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

it just did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is with physics, and a collider.Check the demo below for details.

*For more demos or infos on physics with phaser checkout [these offical examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/physics/arcade) or [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.ArcadePhysics.html)*

**here a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload(){
this.load.image('image1', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/copy-that-floppy.png');
}

function create () {

   let img1 = this.physics.add.image(10, 90, 'image1').setScale(.5);
   
   let img2 = this.physics.add.image(400, 90, 'image1').setScale(.5);
   
   // set velocity to move images
   img1.setVelocityX(50);
   img2.setVelocityX(-50);
   
   // add collider for collision detection
   this.physics.add.collider(img1, img2);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @hackerhq No problem, btw. if my answer help please consider accepting it with the green checkmark under the voting arrows.

Comment: no problem dude